# solrj error executing query

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to execute query

```
http://192.168.1.101:7070/solr/locationList_shard3_replica1/select?q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=geometry&pt=19.7599,74.8091&d=50&sort=geodist()%20desc
```

It works perfectly with solr dashboard but when I tried from solrj error

My code is

```
query.addFilterQuery("{!geofilt}&sfield=geometry&pt="
                    + address.getGeometry() + "&d=1000000&sort=geodist() desc");
```

error missing sfield for spatial request

Comment: specify field name inside Braces & try.  `{!geofilt sfield=geometry}`

Comment: All the special characters (& etc) will be encoded, so they're part of the `fq` parameter - they will not be directly inserted into the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string passed to `addFilterQuery` is the filter parameter. Just to be clear, the string you pass to the method `addFilterQuery` will be entirely encoded. Try to refactor the query in this way:

```
query.add("fq", "{!geofilt}");
query.add("sfield", "geometry");
query.add("pt", address.getGeometry());
query.add("sort", "geodist() desc");
```